# Bootstrap scrollspy within tabs not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

http://htmlcode.allalla.com/

Here is my code up and running.

I am using bootstrap for my application. I am using scrollspy within tabs.
Somehow i have managed to run it but its not working properly in all browsers yet.
In Mozilla its working ok but focus of tab goes on tab2 after the page is loaded.
In IE9 same thing happening , works ok in chrome for now.
Can anyone please tell what is wrong here??

Thanks.